# jQuery: Count words with more than X characters in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have an input field and a textarea in a form. For each of those two fields I'd like to count the number of words, number of dots, and number of words longer than 7 characters.

I've already got the code for the two first numbers (number of words and number of dots), but I can't figure out how to count the number of words longer than 7 characters in each of the fields.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Here is my current code ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4zmuR/)):

```
var titleElem = $('#title');
var numberOfWords = countWords(titleElem);
var numberOfDots = countDots(titleElem);

function countWords(input) {
    var a, z, inputValue, total;
    inputValue = input.val();
    total = 0;
    a = inputValue.replace(/\s/g, ' ');
    a = a.split(' ');
    for (z = 0; z < a.length; z++) { if (a[z].length > 0) total++; }
    return total;
}

function countDots(input) {
    var inputVal;
    inputVal = input.val();

    return inputVal.split(".").length - 1;
}
```

Comment: show your code [and provide a fiddle link also](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: Can you show us the code that you do have?  If you've already got it counting words then what you're asking for should be simple to add it.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I have the folowing code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4zmuR/ The code runs on every keyup event in the input field. The two functions I've got for the counting of words and dots are included in the above link, and works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you classify as a *word*. Does that include hyphens/apostrophes? You could use a simple regex for this:

```
var wordCount = $("input").val().match(/[\w0-9]{8,}/gi).length
```

The `{8,}` ensures that it only captures words more than 7 characters in length.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Actually a good point you've got about how to classify a word. I'd classify a word only by letters and numbers. So any characters like hyphens, brackets, apostrophes etc. should not be included in the count, if that's possible?

Comment: Updated answer. This should allow for word characters (`\w`) and numbers `0-9` only. No "special" characters included.

Comment: Great, it worked! I got an error if there where no words matching saying: "Cannot read property 'length' of null ", so just put the match inside a variable, and then afterwards checking if there where any value and taking the length if so. Thank you very much :)